# Bicycle Fuel equivalent on l/100km

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, everyday-life, physical-chemistry, estimation

Is there a way I can calculate the equivalent how much a Human powered bicycle consumes in  the equivalent l/100 Km of Diesel fuel?

And also can I calculate the same for Gasoline fuel? And for Liquid Petroleum Gas?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to calculate the energy used by the cyclist and divide by the energy density $u$ of your fuel.

$fuel_{per100km}=\frac{100km\cdot P_{cyclist}}{v_{cyclist}\cdot u_{fuel}}$

You may look up the specific values online.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on how fast the bike is being propelled, since going faster requires harder work which burns fuel faster.

The calculation also requires knowledge of the efficiency with which the human body converts, for example, glucose (as fuel) into muscle horsepower, say in watts.

If we are feeding glucose solution to the bicyclist as "fuel", it also requires you to know the glucose concentration in the solution and the energy content of glucose.

You need to know the musculature of the bicyclist too. A trained bicyclist can produce 750 watts of power for 30 to 60 minutes at a time, pedaling as hard as possible. An ordinary bicyclist can produce 300 to 500 watts for 30 to 60 minutes at a time.

These factors will allow you to calculate how many grams of glucose per kilometer of travel a bicyclist "burns".

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

If you drive a bicycle you get this kinetic energy equation

$$E_{\text{B}}=\frac{1}{2}\Theta_1\,(\dot{\theta}_1)^2+\frac{1}{2}\Theta_2\,(\dot{\theta}_2)^2\tag 1$$

with:

$\dot{\theta}_2=i_T\,\dot{\theta}_1$ in equation (1) we obtain:

$$E_{\text{B}}=\frac{1}{2}(\dot{\theta}_1)^2\left(\Theta_1+i_T^2\,\Theta2\right)\tag 2$$

with $\Theta_1\,\ddot{\theta_1}=\tau+F_c\,r_1\quad,
 \Theta_2\,\ddot{\theta_2}=-F_c\,r_2\,\text{and}
\quad ,\ddot{\theta_2}=i_T\,\ddot{\theta_1}\quad$
 $\Rightarrow \quad \dot{\theta_1}=\frac{\tau\,r_2}{r_2\Theta_1+r_1\,\Theta_2\,i_T}\,t$, in  eqaution (2):

$$E_{\text{B}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\tau\,r_2}{r_2\Theta_1+r_1\,\Theta_2\,i_T}\,t\right)^2\left(\Theta_1+i_T^2\,\Theta2\right)\tag 3$$

Where:

$i_T$ transmition coefficient

$\Theta_1\quad,\Theta_2$ Inertia

$\tau$ Human applied torque

Let say for 5 liter you can drive adistance 100 km.
so, if it take you 1 hour to drive  100 km t is:

$t=3600$ [s]

five liter diesel are $49 [Kw\,h]$
$E_\text{car}=49 [Kw\,h] $

$$E_{\text{B}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\tau\,r_2}{r_2\Theta_1+r_1\,\Theta_2\,i_T}\,3600\,\right)^2\left(\Theta_1+i_T^2\,\Theta2\right)
=49=1.764 10^8 [N\,m]\tag 4$$

you can now calculate  the equivalent Human applied torque $\tau$ ,but I don’t think you get a realistic result?